# setSelectedNavigationItem deprecated

Tags: android, view, scroller

I am working on an android app which has two fragments, I came upon a code on the internet to implement view swiper in my app (https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-swipe-view-tab-layout-example.html)
but as I started typing the code I came upon "setSelectedNavigationItem" which showed up as Deprecated .

What can I use instead of setSelectedNavigationItem?

Comment: From documentation: *Consider using other common navigation patterns instead.*  ...

Answer (score 0):

According to [official](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) docs

> setSelectedNavigationItem(int position)

This method was **deprecated** in API level 21. Action bar navigation modes are deprecated and not supported by inline toolbar action bars. Consider using other [common navigation patterns](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) instead.